# php cookie not working after reload

Tags: php, cookies

I am now working on my language script and I use cookies:

```
setcookie("lang", "nl", time() + (24 * 60 * 60));
if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

If I go to mysite/**?lang=en** the site will be in English but when I go to mysite/ is back in the main language (dutch). The cookie is set, I can see the information in Google Chrome but its not working.

Print_r(mysite/) (before set language)

```
Array ( [lang] => nl )
```

Print_r(mysite/?lang=en) (set the new language)

```
Array ( [lang] => en )
```

Print_r(mysite/) (after remove ?lang=en)

```
Array ( [lang] => nl )
```

*I know this script is now unsafe but its not working now. I will add the security after its working.*

Comment: "I will add the security after its working." I hear this so often...

Comment: You should not transfer the info which language is to be served by cookie anyway – it should be part of the URL instead. At least if you want search engines to be able to index the different language version of your page at all.

Comment: My site is only usefull for the Nederlandse Spoorwegen. See Livetrein.nl (here lang script not working, will working soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you set language in cookie each time to "nl", you visit the site, and only if you has `$_GET['lang']` setted, then you set it to another language; but without `$_GET['lang']` its again reseted to "nl".

```
setcookie("lang", "nl", time() + (24 * 60 * 60));

if(isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

It should be:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie("lang", "nl", time() + (24 * 60 * 60));
}

if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    setcookie("lang", $_GET['lang'], time() + (24 * 60 * 60));

    $_COOKIE['lang'] = $_GET['lang'];
}
```

When you use setcookie, it will not be stored in $_COOKIE, only after next load of site.

Comment: Its now only changes after 2 reloads.

Comment: Now its ok, check it.

Comment: Still changes after 2 reloads.

Comment: Fixed by myself: `if (!isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) {
    setcookie("lang", "nl", time() + (24 * 60 * 60));
}

if (isset($_GET['lang'])) {
    $_COOKIE["lang"] = $_GET["lang"];
}`

Comment: Thats wrong, because you have to use setcookie, to set up time, how long cookie will be valid. Your comment will not store in cookies your lang, when you Print_r(mysite/), it will reset it back to "nl"... See my edited answer now.

Comment: Your comment will not store in cookies your lang, when you Print_r(mysite/), it will reset it back to "nl"...